# regex to replace the 6th comma with a line break

Tags: regex

I am trying to replace every 6th comma in the line of text with a line break.  I have tried replacing ,{6} with \n in textpad with no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, the regex you tried matches 6 commas in a row.

Comment: When building regex, try using [this tool](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) to test them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply everyone.  h2oooooo, What app are you using this in?  I think it's a little too involved for textpad.

Answer (score 2):

`/^(([^\n,]+,){5}[^\n,]+),\s*/gm` with replacement `\1\n` should work fine, dependent on your flavour.

`/^((.*?,){5}.*?),\s*/gm` also works fine, but you can't have the DOTALL modifier.

**Input:**

```
this, is, my, string, and, it, is, very, nice, and, pretty, cool
this, is, my, string, and, it, is, very, nice, and, pretty, cool
this, is, my, string, and, it, is, very, nice, and, pretty, cool
this, is, my, string, and, it, is, very, nice, and, pretty, cool
this, is, my, string, and, it, is, very, nice, and, pretty, cool¨
```

**Output:**

```
this, is, my, string, and, it
is, very, nice, and, pretty, cool
this, is, my, string, and, it
is, very, nice, and, pretty, cool
this, is, my, string, and, it
is, very, nice, and, pretty, cool
this, is, my, string, and, it
is, very, nice, and, pretty, cool
this, is, my, string, and, it
is, very, nice, and, pretty, cool
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/yM2gH1)

Comment: What program are using?  This didn't seem to work in textpad.  The text is arranged like this:  G1/1 , G1/2 , G1/3 , and so on...  Would the white space be throwing it off?